# how to parse multiple strings from a linux file

Tags: parsing, awk, grep

I have a script that that I want to parse the username and IP address from.

Here is a sample of the script. this entry exists for all users, about 2000 lines in the script.

```
 if [ "$common_name" = "NUMERICUSERNAME" ]; then
  if [ $(/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -L -v | grep to: | cut -d : -f 2) = "IP.AD.DR.ESS" ] ; then
   /usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s $(/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -L -v | grep IP.AD.DR.ESS | gawk '{ print $(NF-2) }') -j SNAT --to-source IP.AD.DR.ESS ;
  fi
  /usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s $ifconfig_pool_remote_ip -j SNAT --to-source IP.AD.DR.ESS
  fi
```

The username is a 15 digit numeric string.

I have tried parsing with awk...something like `awk '{print $5,$25}' filename` but cant find the correct fields to capture.

I have also tried different forms of grep but do not know how to capture BOTH fields without causing the data to misalign. for example `grep -oP '[0-9-]{10} [0-9:]{8}' filename` gives me all the IPs or all the usernames...but I cant seem to figure out how to get both.

What is the most efficient way to get the output of NUMERICUSERNAME and is matching IP.AD.DR.ESS. something like this

```
NUMERICUSERNAME1 IP.AD.DR.ESS1
NUMERICUSERNAME2 IP.AD.DR.ESS2
....
NUMERICUSERNAME2000 IP.AD.DR.ESS2000
```

Also note that the entry has the IP.AD.DR.ESS in more than one location and that caused me to capture duplicates. can that be avoided as well?

EDIT: output of

```
$ awk '/common_name/ {u = substr($5,2,15)}
       /--to-source/ {print u, $(NF-1)}' < script
```

output:

```
 IP.AD.DR.ESS1
 --to-source
 IP.AD.DR.ESS10
 --to-source
 IP.AD.DR.ESS100
 ...
 IP.AD.DR.ESS75
 --to-source
NUMERICUSERNAME IP.AD.DR.ESS76
SAMENUMERICUSERNAME --to-source
SAMENUMERICUSERNAME IP.AD.DR.ESS77
```

[notepad++ screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMJ9K.png)

EDIT

sample output from solution

```
NUMBERICUSERNAME1 IP.AD.DR.ESS1
NUMBERICUSERNAME1 --to-source
NUMBERICUSERNAME2 IP.AD.DR.ESS2
NUMBERICUSERNAME2 --to-source
```

Comment: Could you be more specific and show an example of the input? It is not clear the format from which you want to extract the information and that makes very difficult to come up with a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, maybe:

```sh
$ awk '/common_name/ {u = substr($5,2,15)}
       /iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING/ {print u, $NF}' < script
NUMERICUSERNAME IP.AD.DR.ESS
```

If the `/common_name/` and/or `/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING/` regular expressions catch unwanted lines you can improve them a bit to make them more selective. Example:

```
/"\$common_name"\s*=\s*"[[:digit:]]{15}"/
```

Comment: that seems to return a single column of all the ip addresses, then repeats the list with two columns. The first column being only a single NUMBERICUSERNAME and the second column a repeated total list of IP addresses. I will post a formatted response in the original post

Comment: This means that the example input you show is not representative of your real input. If you test the proposed awk script with the example input you show it should produce exactly what you ask for. Of course we cannot test it on different inputs that you do not show.

Comment: The example input is one instance of the 581 entries I need to collect. The real sample is only different in the number of entries and changes made to the username and ip of course. does the proposed script depend on the number of entries needed to collect? there is no other difference

Comment: actually the first if is misaligned. I will correct that if it matters.

Comment: nope...I missed the second fi statemen, to close the second if....I apologize  I will add that as well.

Comment: What matters is not the number of such entries. It is their form. As you can see in the awk script, the username is detected in lines that contain the text string `common_name`, as in the example you show. So if you have other entries with usernames in lines that do not contain this text string it cannot work.

Comment: Moreover, the username is extracted from the 5th field of such lines, by retaining only the 15 characters starting from the second. So if you have lines where the username is not a separate word, or not surrounded by double-quotes, this cannot work.

Comment: Same for the IP address. They are detected in lines containing `--to-source` and set to the second to last field (the last one being the semi-colon). If you have entries with that are not formatted as in your example, that is, without a line ending with `--to-source IP.AD.DR.ESS ;` (with at least one space between the 3 words), then it cannot work.

Comment: Anyway, try to look carefully at your real input and to give a representative example of it in your question. For instance, we cannot guess if some entries have different newlines or if there are lines without a space before the ending semi-colon. It is up to you to describe your inputs in the most possible accurate way. Each detail matters.

Comment: By the way, after your editing something important changed: in the first version there was only one `--to-source` per entry. Now there are 2. This is the kind of things that changes everything, and one reason why the proposed awk script does not work any more. Is the new version **really** representative?

Comment: I apologize for the oversight. I should have caught that before posting. I have double checked the sample and it is accurate. I have also added a screenshot from notepad++ showing all characters and whitespace. though the image is only showing as a link in my edit the link seems to work.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer to reflect your changes. But considering the outputs you got with the previous version I doubt that it will be sufficient. I suspect other differences in other entries...

Comment: that worked great! used notepad++ to do a little cleaning up. I copied the sample output edited in the post. can you advise what the `$NF`  string is doing?

Comment: ah...also need to add that it looks like i was applying `awk` to the wrong file. I made backups of the original as to not mess with it. and couple of the outputs of the backup are similarly named, and i did not realize i was manipulating the wrong file.